# Tor has an error right after installation

Tags: windows, error

I just downloaded tor and after opening it got the "Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start." First of all i havent edited the torrc file, also i ve tried deleting and reinstalling tor and it doesnt work. I just did a factory reset on my laptop and before that i had downloaded tor and nothing like that had ever happened. Help pls couldnt find any answers online. Lastly i am using windows 10 if thats helpful

Comment: Please attach the error log to your question, without it it's impossible to even guess a reason. Also - what antivirus software do you have?

Comment: I have the mcafee one and the windows protection but i turned them both off while reinstalling it and it still happened. Also what do you mean by the "error log"? The error message that shows up was this : "Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start."

Comment: help please cmon :(

Comment: I'm here, don't worry :) Error logs are here https://support.torproject.org/tbb/tbb-21/ - just follow the instruction. For Windows I do recommend you BitDefender TotalSecurity - McAffee is a broblem bag since it's author quited it.